# onMonthChanged event in JQM Datebox

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I cannot find an "onMonthChanged" event on the jqm Datebox. Is there any event that fires when the user presses the arrow button to change month in the control?

Any alternative solution to catch this user action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like {'method'} === offset does this. Just a question of me not understanding the [API docs](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/events.html).

```
$('#mydate').bind('datebox', function (e, p) {
    if (p.method === 'offset') {
        alert(p.amount);
    }
});
```